# State the range of $f(x) = x^2-1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> State the range of $f(x) = x^2 - 1$, $x\in\mathbb R$.

I was just wondering how I might do this one, because I've noticed that the domain is infinite.

Is the range just literally:

$y$ is greater than $-1$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: yes. greater than or equal to -1. [-1,infinity)

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is better than "$x$ is the real numbers" because your original formulation could mean $x$ is a set.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=f(x)=x^2-1$, where $y$ is the range of the function.

So, $x^2=y+1\tag{1}$

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $x^2 \geq 0\tag{2}$

Putting $(1)$ in $(2)$, we get $$y +1 \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow y \geq -1$$

Answer (score 1):

Find the minimum of $f(x)$ and show by calculus that it's increasing in both directions either side of that point.  That proves that $y\geq-1$.

Answer (score 0):

An approach through graph transformations:

The range of the function $g(x) = x^2$ is $[0, \infty)$ since $g(0) = 0$, $g(x) = x^2 \geq 0$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)$ is continuous, and $g(x)$ increases without bound as $|x| \to \infty$.

Recall that the graph of $y = x^2$ is a parabola with vertex at the origin that opens upwards, as shown in blue below.  The graph of the function $f(x) = x^2 - 1$ is the parabola $y = x^2 - 1$.  The graph of $y = x^2 - 1$ can be obtained from the graph of $y = x^2$ by shifting the graph of $y = x^2$ down by one unit, as shown in green below.  Hence, its range is $[-1, \infty)$.

[image: transformation_of_parabola]

In general, the graph of $y = a(x - h)^2 + k$, with $a \neq 0$, is a parabola with vertex $(h, k)$ that opens upwards if $a > 0$ and downwards if $a < 0$.  If $a > 0$, the range of $f(x) = a(x - h)^2 + k$ is $[k, \infty)$.  If $a < 0$, the range of $f(x) = a(x - h)^2 + k$ is $(-\infty, k]$.